# Terraform AWS Lambda CI/CD with function code in separate repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I have a repository that contains all of my terraform code, including an `aws_apigatewayv2_api` resource and other relevant resources like stages. I want to set up lambda integrations for each of this API Gateway's routes, but I don't want the lambda runtime code to be in the same repository as my infrastructure. I would like the code for each lambda to have its own repository and independent CI/CD pipeline, such that code changes to the lambda don't require terraform to look at the rest of the infrastructure on apply (basically, a separate terraform state for each lambda). The problem is, I don't know how to do this while allowing each lambda's respective `aws_apigatewayv2_integration` resource to see both the `aws_api_gatewayv2` and the `aws_lambda_function` that it needs.

**Are these my only options?**

- Utilize `terraform_remote_state` in each lambda's terraform to allow it to see into the core infrastructure state where the `aws_apigatewayv2_api` is located (but if the core infra is updated in a way that breaks the lambda integration, the lambda will have no way of knowing until it gets a new CI trigger).
- Write all the lambda code in the same repository as the infrastructure. One repository, one CI pipeline.

I don't like either of these options because I either lose separation of runtime code and infrastructure, or I lose the ability for the lambdas' terraform to stay in sync with the core terraform. **Is there a third solution**, ideally allowing me to maintain both of these desired qualities?

Answer (score 0):

The third solution would be using a serverless framework besides Terraform, I used Terraform to manage Lambda and API gateway in the past, its headache un-needed.

use `infra` folder for **Terraform** and `serverless` or `app` folder for **serverless** framework.

Mono Repo is gaining popularity these days.

**Keep in mind:**

- **Terraform** is best suited for managing more persistent shared infrastructure
- **Serverless** is a good fit to manage the application-specific infrastructure.

***Example:***

- https://github.com/chief-wizard/serverless-terraform-example